# Rails Sidekiq worker preform_in with dynamic interval number

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

For the `Worker.perform_in(1.hour)` method how could I write it so that the number 1 was a dynamic variable?

I would like to write something like:

`Worker.perform_in(a.hours)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote will work fine:

```
a = 1
Worker.perform_in(a.hours)
```